# How to programatically know the current region in an azure role?

Tags: azure

I need to programmatically find the current region (e.g "West US" or "East US") where my current role is running. Is there any API to find this?

Comment: Do you need to find it from within the role or from outside?

Comment: Gaurav, are you saying you can find it without the management api from within the role it self :) ?

Comment: @pksorensen You would still need to use management api but there you would have to go bottoms up. If the code is running in the role, you would have deployment id. You would then loop through all the cloud services to find matching deployment id and then fetch the properties of the cloud service like you mentioned in your answer below.

Comment: Hehe, just hoped you had implemented something new for us ;)

Comment: LOL! Really old blog post and a bit off topic but this should help: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/03/16/programmatically-finding-deployment-slot-from-code-running-in-windows-azure/.

Answer (score 2):

You can only get that information if you use the Management Api.

Either by REST or you can use the c# Windows Azure Management Libraries (Prerelease on nuget).

But due note that you need to set up management certificates to get the information.

An easier alternative is to create a setting in your cloud service and set the values when you create the deployment configuration. I do this and have deployment configurations for the regions I target.

```
    using( var azure = CloudContext.Clients.CreateComputeManagementClient(...))
    {
       var service = await  azure.HostedServices.GetDetailedAsync("servicename");
      //   service.Properties.Location
      //  service.Properties.AffinityGroup;

    }
    using(var azure = CloudContext.Clients.CreateManagementClient(...))
    {
      var affinityGroup = await  azure.AffinityGroups.GetAsync("name",new CancellationToken());
      //  affinityGroup.Location
    }
```

Here ... is the credentials, either a management certificate or your WAAD oauth tokens.
(ADAL : Active Directory Authentication Library) can be used for tokens.

here is the code for getting credentials from a certificate:

```
    public static CertificateCloudCredentials GetCertificateCloudCredentials(
        string certificateThumbprint, string subscriptionId)
    {
        var certificate = CertificateHelper.LoadCertificate(
            StoreName.My,
            StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
            certificateThumbprint);

        if (certificate == null)
            throw new Exception(
                string.Format("Certificate with thumbprint '{0}' not found",
                certificateThumbprint));

        var cred = new CertificateCloudCredentials(
            subscriptionId,
            certificate
         );
        return cred;
    }
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful to illustrate the actual API call that provides this functionality (same with the C# method).

Comment: It depends on what route is taken. I can give the c# code for c# management libraries in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Get Cloud Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx) in the service management API. When you supply the service that your roles are a part of, you can retrieve a response similar to the following. Note the location field that I've starred.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HostedService xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
  <Url>hosted-service-url</Url>
  <ServiceName>hosted-service-name</ServiceName>
  <HostedServiceProperties>
    <Description>description</Description>
    <AffinityGroup>name-of-affinity-group</AffinityGroup> 
    **<Location>location-of-service</Location >**
    <Label>base-64-encoded-name-of-service</Label>
    <Status>current-status-of-service</Status>
    <DateCreated>creation-date-of-service</DateCreated>
    <DateLastModified>last-modification-date-of-service</DateLastModified>
    <ExtendedProperties>
      <ExtendedProperty>
        <Name>name-of-property</Name>
        <Value>value-of-property</Value>
      </ExtendedProperty>
    </ExtendedProperties>
    <GuestAgentType>type-of-guest-agent</GuestAgentType>
  </HostedServiceProperties>
  <DefaultWinRmCertificateThumbprint>thumbprint-of-winrm-certificate</DefaultWinRmCertificateThumbprint>
</HostedService>
```

Comment: Adding to @GregD's answer: Please note that location field will not be returned if your cloud service is part of an affinity group. In that case, you need to fetch the properties of an affinity group and get the location of that affinity group. That would also be the location of the cloud service.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460789.aspx << Get Affinity Group Properties api.

Comment: This is the same information you get from the C# Managmement libraries. In deployment we have all our affinity groups appended with -weu -wus -sea  for west europe ect and its then easy to know where affinity groups are located. Again. Its simple to put the meta data into the deployment file as a setting and saves alot of time having to get the info from management api.

Answer (score 1):

That information is available from the [Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service). The REST endpoint for any VM running in the Azure public cloud is `http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-04-02`. The metadata object contains two sub-objects, one for "compute" and one for "network". The region name appears in the "location" member of the "compute" object.

Sample code in multiple languages for accessing various elements of IMDS data are available from the [Microsoft/azureimds repo on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azureimds). Far more information than I show here is available through the 2018-10-01 version of the IMDS API; see [IMDS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service) for details.

```
$ curl -s -H Metadata:True "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-04-02&format=json" | jq .
{
  "compute": {
    "location": "westus2",
    "name": "samplevm",
    "offer": "UbuntuServer",
    "osType": "Linux",
    "platformFaultDomain": "0",
    "platformUpdateDomain": "0",
    "publisher": "Canonical",
    "sku": "18.04-LTS",
    "version": "18.04.201904020",
    "vmId": "(redacted)",
    "vmSize": "Standard_D2s_v3"
  },
  "network": {
    "interface": [
      {
        "ipv4": {
          "ipAddress": [
            {
              "privateIpAddress": "10.0.0.7",
              "publicIpAddress": ""
            }
          ],
          "subnet": [
            {
              "address": "10.0.0.0",
              "prefix": "24"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ipv6": {
          "ipAddress": []
        },
        "macAddress": "(redacted)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```