# How to get the location of a azure worker role?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cloud-services

How can I get the location (e.g. US West, Europe North) of a worker role progromatically from .Net?

I've been looking around this:

```
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role
```

But can't find the Location anywhere.

Also how do you get the **current Role VM Size**?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999841/how-to-programatically-know-the-current-region-in-an-azure-role

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check out the classic [REST api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx) for Azure Management.There is a method called "Get Deployment", which gets the properties for the cloud service role.Basically the response would contain a bunch of attributes. I certainly remember using it for the role size. But not sure about the location.

Hope this helps!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx