# How to programatically determine the cloud location of my ASP.net cloud service?

Tags: azure

I have a ASP.net web api running in an Azure cloud service. I want to know the current cloud location for logging purposes on every request made to the web api (for example: "Central US" and "West US").

Is there an azure api for accessing this information from the box on which my code is running (so no network call needs to be made)?

Comment: Try exploring `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance` but i kind of doubt it contains the region - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.currentroleinstance.aspx. You probably have a better chance storing the region name in an environment variable and reading it from your role. Needless to say this requires redeployment. There should be a better way though..

Comment: Check this post in Stack overflow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999841/how-to-programatically-know-the-current-region-in-an-azure-role